# output mysql data into variables for jquery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, variables

I have a 2 field database (daynumber & datavalue), the data of which I am retrieving with php then creating and passing variables into jquery for use with a graph.

I am not doing this as an array because I need to apply a formula to the datavalue field. The formula can be altered by the user.

In jquery, I need to be able to do this:

```
cday_1 = <?php echo $day_1?>;
cday_2 = <?php echo $day_2?>;
tday_1 = (<?php echo $day_1 ?> * formula1 / formula2;
tday_2 = (<?php echo $day_2 ?> * formula1 / formula2;
```

The cday series and the tday series will be plotted separately on the graph.

My problem is that I could manually name each var in php, ie:

```
$day_1=mysql_result($result,$i,"datavalue");
```

but I have 30 rows and I'd prefer to do it with a loop.  So far, I've got this far:

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
$datavalue=mysql_result($result,$i,"datavalue");
echo "\$day_";
echo $i;
echo " = ";
echo $datavalue;
echo "<br>";
$i++;
}
```

So there are a couple of problems I'm having with this.

The first problem is that while everything is echoing, I'm not sure how to actually create variables like this(!).

The second problem is that there are only 30 rows in the db, but 34 are actually outputting and I can't work out why.

I'm self-taught, so apologies for clumsy coding and/or stupid questions.

Comment: I don't think I explained myself properly. Worked out how to do it myself and have added the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have ended up doing this:

```
$i=0;
while ($i < $num) {
${"day_$i"}=mysql_result($result,$i,"datavalue");
$i++;
}
```

I have a feeling this was a basic issue and I just didn't explain myself properly. I am unable to use an array as I needed to fiddle with formulas so this solution worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could just store them in a PHP-side array:

```
$days = array(
    'cday' => 'the cday value',
    'dday' => 'the dday value',
    etc...
);
```

and then via `json_encode()` translate them to a Javascript array/object automatically. This object could be sent to your page as an AJAX response, or even embedded into the page directly:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var days = <?php echo json_encode($days) ?>;
</script>
```

after which you just access the values as you would any other array in JS.

Comment: Would this work with my formula that I need to apply to the 2nd series: `tday_1 = (<?php echo $day_1 ?> * formula1 / formula2;`? The page has buttons through which the formula/value is altered, ie: `$('#change1up').click(function() {
formfig=formfig+3;
chartdraw();
});`

Comment: Not directly, since formula1/formula2 are Javascript variables - PHP would have no knowledge of them, unless PHP generated them in the first place. However, nothing says you can't massage the array from within JS afterwards. At least this method saves you having to specify them one-by-one for the basic original values.